# Proper title for a French man prior to Monsieur

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, société

I am writing historical fiction, so pretty good with research. But I am stumped by the use of Monsieur. I realize it was used by royalty referring to the brother of a king. However now it is used as a title for French-speaking gentlemen.

What I cannot find is what title was used for a gentleman prior to its modern general use?

I appreciate any assistance as I cannot find an answer anywhere online.

Comment: Welcome to French Language Stack Exchange! Please take the **[tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)** and visit the **[Help Centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)** at some point, and we hope you continue to ask questions. Unfortunately, I can't answer this particular one, but there are a few other editors who very likely can. :)

Comment: When is your writing set? “Prior to its modern general use” is not a precise time period. And where? French is more unified today than it used to be.

Comment: That's a really limited view.  'Monsieur' by itself was used for Louis XIV's brother.  But that was because he was the most important of his contemporaries, not because that was a title used for all of a king's brothers, or that he initiated it in any way.  Monsieur So-and-so was a common title for general nobility, used for centuries before.  It'd be helpful if you'd give us a century for your fiction?

Comment: Years too late in a response but I am also writing a historical fiction novel in 16th century France and could not find a definitive answer regarding titles of non-aristocracy. I guess that I will use "sir (sieur)" as you did!

Answer (score 3):

In the Middle-Ages a man of certain importance was addressed as *Monsor*. The word started being spelt *Monsieur* in the 16th century.

*Monsor - Monsieur* is the contraction of *Mon - Sieur* (My Lord).

*Sieur* continued being used in front of a man's name, without an initial capital in legal writings. At that time when used in a novel, it gave an ironical or derogatory tone.

Comment: I certainly appreciate you quick response! Merci.
I believe all it could be is Sieur. It is all I can find.
Can you tell me if Sieur capitalized when used BEFORE a gentleman's name Such as Sier Daniel Boyd Or should it be sier Daniel Boyd
Every translator gives me something different.
Vee

Answer (score 2):

En référence à la célèbre [scène du réveil](https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=il+est+l%27or+monseignor) du film "La folie des grandeurs", je propose *Monseigneur* (prononcé monseignor dans l'extrait pour la rime).